# Integrate pdf excel word viewer on a website

Tags: excel, pdf, web, ms-word, viewer

I would like to integrate a viewer tool for viewing files in pdf, excel, word formats. I am developing a website that store manuals and I would like visitors to have an ability to view these manuals online instead of downloading. I found a tool named ViewerJS that can view PDF and Open Documents online. However the tool doesn't support Microsoft Office.

Comment: You'll most likely have to use two (or more) viewing tools. However this is not the place to look for them. [Software Reccomendations](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) would be appropriate with a tinsy bit of editing - I'd be happy to help with the editing if you have troubles figuring out the required post quality there (if so just email me or tag me in a comment)

Comment: Thank much @NickWilde. I am a new user in this website. Your help would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You should probably use the Google Drive API

https://developers.google.com/discovery/libraries & https://developers.google.com/picker/docs/

Comment: Thank Bijan.Is this possible if we host files on our server and use Google Picker to view these files?